# Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu edition usable in United States?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, aquaris

Can the Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu edition currently being sold in Europe (http://www.bq.com/gb/aquaris-e4-5-ubuntu-edition) be used in the United States with an American SIM card/service provider? A friend is traveling to Europe and I was thinking of asking them to pick one up for me if it'd be possible to use it here.

Comment: I don't think it comes with operator-locked. So you might be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you will have to consider:

1. You need a power adapter. That should be no problem.
2. You have to check if US service providers use one of these 3G HSPA+ (900/2100), 2G GSM (850/900/1800/1900) frequencies.
   In the US the frequencies 850 and 1900 are used, and hence the phone should work. This seems to be verified by some US users on youtube. (The phone is unlocked).
3. At least here, the phone is not available in shops. So you might want to order it in time to the European address, where your friend is going to stay.

The phone is definitely worth a try, though sometimes still rough around the edges (ubuntu-touch), but getting regular updates...